# I'm gettng the error when starting weblogic 12.1.3 with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic12c

I'm using spring boot (web) with weblogic 12.1.3. getting the below error when i right-click run-on server.
Error:

```
<Oct 25, 2016 3:53:23 PM EDT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101394> <The exception "The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when processing getParameter or getParameterValues from a multipart value of a ServletRequest.>
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>gov.maine.print</groupId>
    <artifactId>PrintNotice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>PrintNoticeService</name>
    <description>Notice print for batch and online</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.9.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <archive>
               <manifest>
                  <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
               </manifest>
            </archive>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>PrintNotice</wls:context-root>
     <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

### Restcontroller call

```
@RestController

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String readResource() {
        return "HI.......";
    }
```

Would someone help?

Comment: what are you trying to do? point of spring-boot plugin is to enable running jar as standalone, but it seems you want to build a .war?

Comment: also, what is the error you're getting? You're only showing a warning, not any error.

Comment: That is warning message, when i try to invoke the resource using IE, It's giving me a attachment file rather than "HI......." message response. But the same is working as expected on FireFox and Chrome.

Comment: First of all I want to say thank you for your quick response.

Comment: that doesn't sound like an issue with deployment at all. Have you checked the content-type of the response? Have you tried to specify it through `@RequestMapping(produces = ...)`? If you're trying to return a string, why don't you use `@RequestBody` for your method?

Comment: Yes I tried, it doesn't help. It looking for the request content-type LIKE =The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data" occurred when processing getParameter or getParameterValues from a multipart value of a ServletRequest.                                                                                       So I used @RequestMapping(consumes="text/html") also. But no luck

Comment: So you tried both? multipart/form-data relates to a form or POST method but you haven't said anything about either?

Comment: I have not used PSOT. I used HTTP method as GET.

Comment: would you please share some sample code for @RequestBody. The warning or error message comes when i deploy the application

Comment: Added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this information from a comment:

> That is warning message, when i try to invoke the resource using IE,
>   It's giving me a attachment file rather than "HI......." message
>   response. But the same is working as expected on FireFox and Chrome.

You should add `@RequestBody` annotation, as well as content type using `produces=...` to your `readResource()` method. That way Spring will know that you're trying to return response content, with correct content-type, and not a name of a view to render for example.

Example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="text/html")
@RequestBody
String readResource() {
        return "HI.......";
}
```

Comment: I just replace my actual code with example code which you gave me, Getting the error like- The annotation @RequestBody is disallowed for this location

Comment: @Bala then you have additional code there that you haven't shown. You'll need to provide all relevant code / MCVE. See [details here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I cannot reproduce your problem.